# Owl-carousel. Проблема с width при обновлении страницы

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel, width

Столкнулся с проблемой. На ПК версии сайта (Широкий экран) при загрузке страницы карусель отображается нормально.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но после того как обновляю страницу - справа вылезает край другого изображения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При чём если уменьшить/увеличить размер окна, то карусель снова станет нормальной. Но стоит обновить и всё снова летит.

Вот что ещё успел раскопать.

Тут вместе с консолью.
До обновления страницы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После обновления страницы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примечательно стало то, что просвет идёт не в процентном соотношении, а ровно на 15 пикселей вне зависимости от начальных размеров окна.

Выяснилось, что страница считает, что там есть scroll страницы на этом месте. Если к тэгу body приписать overflow-y:hidden, то всё как по маслу.

Answer (score 2):

```
var owl = $("#slider_container");
owl.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
```

После подключения карусели.
И вуаля